# Clarification on separability in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On pg 45 of Baby Rudin we have:

> **22.** A metric space is called *separable* if it contains a countable dense subset.
>
> **24.** Let $X$ be a metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit point. Prove that $X$ is separable.
>
> **25**. Prove that every compact metric space $K$ ... is separable.

Since "countable" is defined in Rudin to exclusively mean "infinite and countable", then clearly the results don't hold for finite metric spaces, since that would imply an infinite set is a subset of a finite one.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: He should have included finite as OK too.

Comment: Clearly, "countable" in 22 means "finite or infinite countable"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, Walter Rudin, in the *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, p.25, defines as *countable* set one which is equinumerous to $\mathbb N$. In the same page, he defines what is an *at most countable* set.

So, in **22** the term *countable* should be replaced by *at most countable* to be consistent with itself.